# How to make clickable text in Lazy Column

Tags: android, kotlin, onclick, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn

I am trying to build a basic hymn book application.

So I have the top app bar and. A lazy column containing the list of songs.

```
@Composable
fun Songs(){
    val listofsongs = listOfSongs()
    val getALlData = listofsongs.getAllData()

    LazyColumn(
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(all= 5.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
    ){
        items(items = getALlData){ song ->
             SongView(song = song)
        }
    }
}
```

The view of the song item takes a clickable text wrapped in a box.

```
@Composable
fun SongView(
    song: Song,
) {

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(2.dp)
                .border(BorderStroke(2.dp, Color.Black))
                .clickable {context.StartActivity(Intent(context, HymnActivity:class.java)},
        ) {

            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(15.dp),
                text = "${song.text}",
                fontSize = 15.sp,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold,
                color = Color.Black
            )

            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .align(Alignment.TopEnd)
                    .padding(15.dp),
                text = "${song.number}",
                fontSize = 20.sp,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                color = Color.Black

            )

        }
    }
```

I want to make each clickable button lead to a new screen with the appropriate song. I tried using

`context.StartActivity(Intent(context, HymnActivity:class.java)`

Which kept going to one song.

The lazy column gets the name and number of the song from the data class Song

> ```
> data class Song(
>     val text:String,
>     val number:Int,
> )
> ```

I tried creating a different data class containing the items in the view then linking the items with different comparable functions also.

The link to the [Github](https://github.com/Opeoluwa-Muritala/Songs_Of_The_Kingdom)

[UI of application in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQQ2K.jpg)

Comment: Instead of trying to achieve opening a new screen for every song. Make a common screen and load the required song on that screen.

Comment: When opening a new screen, pass the song info with the intent(putExtra) and load that song into the new screen. Does this help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a good approach to have a specific screen for each song. Instead, pass the data to the next screen.
You can pass the song to the next screen via Intent:

First add `onClick` function to your `SongView` composable and call it in `Modifier.clickable`

```
@Composable
fun SongView(
    song: Song,
    onClick:()->Unit
) {

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(2.dp)
                .border(BorderStroke(2.dp, Color.Black))
                .clickable {onClick()},
        ) {
}
```

Next in your screen you can start Intent and send the song using putExtra:

```
LazyColumn(
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(all= 5.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
    ){
        items(items = getALlData){ song ->
             SongView(song = song,onClick = { 
                 context.StartActivity(Intent(context, 
                     HymnActivity:class.java).apply{
                         putExtra("SONG_KEY",song)
            } })
        }
    }
```